# DataTables: Change frame, font and alignment of selector

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I have problems with adjusting the page selector from DataTables.

I was able to change the background color to black but the frame around it is still blue. Same with the font color of the pages which are not selected and the "Next" button.

Can you help me?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v4324v7s/)

```
td{
    padding: 3px !important;
}

.selector:checked{
background-color:black !important;
}

.pagination > li.active > a{
      background-color:black !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to consider focused state of button:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#table1").DataTable({
    searching: false
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 3px !important;
}

selector:checked {
  background-color: black !important;
}

.pagination>li.active>a {
  background-color: black !important;
}

.pagination>li>a:focus,
.pagination>li.active>a {
  outline-color: red;
  border-color:red;
}

.dataTables_paginate>.pagination>li:not(.active)>a{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="table1_paginate">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="paginate_button previous disabled" id="table1_previous"><a href="#" aria-controls="table1" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="paginate_button active"><a href="#" aria-controls="table1" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a></li>
    <li class="paginate_button "><a href="#" aria-controls="table1" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a></li>
    <li class="paginate_button "><a href="#" aria-controls="table1" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0">3</a></li>
    <li class="paginate_button "><a href="#" aria-controls="table1" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0">4</a></li>
    <li class="paginate_button "><a href="#" aria-controls="table1" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0">5</a></li>
    <li class="paginate_button disabled" id="table1_ellipsis"><a href="#" aria-controls="table1" data-dt-idx="6" tabindex="0">…</a></li>
    <li class="paginate_button "><a href="#" aria-controls="table1" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0">20</a></li>
    <li class="paginate_button next" id="table1_next"><a href="#" aria-controls="table1" data-dt-idx="8" tabindex="0">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>





<title>Table</title>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <!--    <div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Overview</a>
  </div> -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
        <li class="inactive"><a href="#">example</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <table id="table1" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="50">
      <thead class="thead-inverse">

        <tr style="border-width: 1px">
          <th class="text-nowrap">example1</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap">example2</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap">example3</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap">example4</th>
          <th class="text-nowrap">example5</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Quisque facilisis condimentum massa, mollis interdum dui maximus in.</td>
          <td>Aliquam interdum est vel ligula tempor pellentesque.</td>
          <td> Quisque mattis ligula ultrices libero malesuada pulvinar</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>2</td>
          <td>vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
          <td>Vestibulum nulla tortor, rhoncus quis quam quis, tempus ultrices leo.</td>
          <td>Cras accumsan accumsan elit sit amet posuere</td>
          <td>Praesent tempus libero lorem, vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>3</td>
          <td>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Praesent tristique vitae orci eget interdum.</td>
          <td>Donec eu lorem faucibus, tempor leo a, maximus nibh.</td>
          <td> Sed ut venenatis ligula, eget faucibus sapien</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Quisque facilisis condimentum massa, mollis interdum dui maximus in.</td>
          <td>Aliquam interdum est vel ligula tempor pellentesque.</td>
          <td> Quisque mattis ligula ultrices libero malesuada pulvinar</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>2</td>
          <td>vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
          <td>Vestibulum nulla tortor, rhoncus quis quam quis, tempus ultrices leo.</td>
          <td>Cras accumsan accumsan elit sit amet posuere</td>
          <td>Praesent tempus libero lorem, vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>3</td>
          <td>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Praesent tristique vitae orci eget interdum.</td>
          <td>Donec eu lorem faucibus, tempor leo a, maximus nibh.</td>
          <td> Sed ut venenatis ligula, eget faucibus sapien</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Quisque facilisis condimentum massa, mollis interdum dui maximus in.</td>
          <td>Aliquam interdum est vel ligula tempor pellentesque.</td>
          <td> Quisque mattis ligula ultrices libero malesuada pulvinar</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>2</td>
          <td>vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
          <td>Vestibulum nulla tortor, rhoncus quis quam quis, tempus ultrices leo.</td>
          <td>Cras accumsan accumsan elit sit amet posuere</td>
          <td>Praesent tempus libero lorem, vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>3</td>
          <td>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Praesent tristique vitae orci eget interdum.</td>
          <td>Donec eu lorem faucibus, tempor leo a, maximus nibh.</td>
          <td> Sed ut venenatis ligula, eget faucibus sapien</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Quisque facilisis condimentum massa, mollis interdum dui maximus in.</td>
          <td>Aliquam interdum est vel ligula tempor pellentesque.</td>
          <td> Quisque mattis ligula ultrices libero malesuada pulvinar</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>2</td>
          <td>vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
          <td>Vestibulum nulla tortor, rhoncus quis quam quis, tempus ultrices leo.</td>
          <td>Cras accumsan accumsan elit sit amet posuere</td>
          <td>Praesent tempus libero lorem, vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>3</td>
          <td>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Praesent tristique vitae orci eget interdum.</td>
          <td>Donec eu lorem faucibus, tempor leo a, maximus nibh.</td>
          <td> Sed ut venenatis ligula, eget faucibus sapien</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Quisque facilisis condimentum massa, mollis interdum dui maximus in.</td>
          <td>Aliquam interdum est vel ligula tempor pellentesque.</td>
          <td> Quisque mattis ligula ultrices libero malesuada pulvinar</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>2</td>
          <td>vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
          <td>Vestibulum nulla tortor, rhoncus quis quam quis, tempus ultrices leo.</td>
          <td>Cras accumsan accumsan elit sit amet posuere</td>
          <td>Praesent tempus libero lorem, vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>3</td>
          <td>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Praesent tristique vitae orci eget interdum.</td>
          <td>Donec eu lorem faucibus, tempor leo a, maximus nibh.</td>
          <td> Sed ut venenatis ligula, eget faucibus sapien</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Quisque facilisis condimentum massa, mollis interdum dui maximus in.</td>
          <td>Aliquam interdum est vel ligula tempor pellentesque.</td>
          <td> Quisque mattis ligula ultrices libero malesuada pulvinar</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>2</td>
          <td>vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
          <td>Vestibulum nulla tortor, rhoncus quis quam quis, tempus ultrices leo.</td>
          <td>Cras accumsan accumsan elit sit amet posuere</td>
          <td>Praesent tempus libero lorem, vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>3</td>
          <td>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Praesent tristique vitae orci eget interdum.</td>
          <td>Donec eu lorem faucibus, tempor leo a, maximus nibh.</td>
          <td> Sed ut venenatis ligula, eget faucibus sapien</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Quisque facilisis condimentum massa, mollis interdum dui maximus in.</td>
          <td>Aliquam interdum est vel ligula tempor pellentesque.</td>
          <td> Quisque mattis ligula ultrices libero malesuada pulvinar</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>2</td>
          <td>vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
          <td>Vestibulum nulla tortor, rhoncus quis quam quis, tempus ultrices leo.</td>
          <td>Cras accumsan accumsan elit sit amet posuere</td>
          <td>Praesent tempus libero lorem, vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>3</td>
          <td>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Praesent tristique vitae orci eget interdum.</td>
          <td>Donec eu lorem faucibus, tempor leo a, maximus nibh.</td>
          <td> Sed ut venenatis ligula, eget faucibus sapien</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Quisque facilisis condimentum massa, mollis interdum dui maximus in.</td>
          <td>Aliquam interdum est vel ligula tempor pellentesque.</td>
          <td> Quisque mattis ligula ultrices libero malesuada pulvinar</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>2</td>
          <td>vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
          <td>Vestibulum nulla tortor, rhoncus quis quam quis, tempus ultrices leo.</td>
          <td>Cras accumsan accumsan elit sit amet posuere</td>
          <td>Praesent tempus libero lorem, vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>3</td>
          <td>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Praesent tristique vitae orci eget interdum.</td>
          <td>Donec eu lorem faucibus, tempor leo a, maximus nibh.</td>
          <td> Sed ut venenatis ligula, eget faucibus sapien</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Quisque facilisis condimentum massa, mollis interdum dui maximus in.</td>
          <td>Aliquam interdum est vel ligula tempor pellentesque.</td>
          <td> Quisque mattis ligula ultrices libero malesuada pulvinar</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>2</td>
          <td>vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
          <td>Vestibulum nulla tortor, rhoncus quis quam quis, tempus ultrices leo.</td>
          <td>Cras accumsan accumsan elit sit amet posuere</td>
          <td>Praesent tempus libero lorem, vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>3</td>
          <td>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Praesent tristique vitae orci eget interdum.</td>
          <td>Donec eu lorem faucibus, tempor leo a, maximus nibh.</td>
          <td> Sed ut venenatis ligula, eget faucibus sapien</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Quisque facilisis condimentum massa, mollis interdum dui maximus in.</td>
          <td>Aliquam interdum est vel ligula tempor pellentesque.</td>
          <td> Quisque mattis ligula ultrices libero malesuada pulvinar</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>2</td>
          <td>vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
          <td>Vestibulum nulla tortor, rhoncus quis quam quis, tempus ultrices leo.</td>
          <td>Cras accumsan accumsan elit sit amet posuere</td>
          <td>Praesent tempus libero lorem, vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>3</td>
          <td>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Praesent tristique vitae orci eget interdum.</td>
          <td>Donec eu lorem faucibus, tempor leo a, maximus nibh.</td>
          <td> Sed ut venenatis ligula, eget faucibus sapien</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Quisque facilisis condimentum massa, mollis interdum dui maximus in.</td>
          <td>Aliquam interdum est vel ligula tempor pellentesque.</td>
          <td> Quisque mattis ligula ultrices libero malesuada pulvinar</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>2</td>
          <td>vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
          <td>Vestibulum nulla tortor, rhoncus quis quam quis, tempus ultrices leo.</td>
          <td>Cras accumsan accumsan elit sit amet posuere</td>
          <td>Praesent tempus libero lorem, vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>3</td>
          <td>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Praesent tristique vitae orci eget interdum.</td>
          <td>Donec eu lorem faucibus, tempor leo a, maximus nibh.</td>
          <td> Sed ut venenatis ligula, eget faucibus sapien</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Quisque facilisis condimentum massa, mollis interdum dui maximus in.</td>
          <td>Aliquam interdum est vel ligula tempor pellentesque.</td>
          <td> Quisque mattis ligula ultrices libero malesuada pulvinar</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>2</td>
          <td>vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
          <td>Vestibulum nulla tortor, rhoncus quis quam quis, tempus ultrices leo.</td>
          <td>Cras accumsan accumsan elit sit amet posuere</td>
          <td>Praesent tempus libero lorem, vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>3</td>
          <td>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Praesent tristique vitae orci eget interdum.</td>
          <td>Donec eu lorem faucibus, tempor leo a, maximus nibh.</td>
          <td> Sed ut venenatis ligula, eget faucibus sapien</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Quisque facilisis condimentum massa, mollis interdum dui maximus in.</td>
          <td>Aliquam interdum est vel ligula tempor pellentesque.</td>
          <td> Quisque mattis ligula ultrices libero malesuada pulvinar</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>2</td>
          <td>vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
          <td>Vestibulum nulla tortor, rhoncus quis quam quis, tempus ultrices leo.</td>
          <td>Cras accumsan accumsan elit sit amet posuere</td>
          <td>Praesent tempus libero lorem, vel ultrices sem sodales at</td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="border-width: 1px;">
          <td>3</td>
          <td>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
          <td>Praesent tristique vitae orci eget interdum.</td>
          <td>Donec eu lorem faucibus, tempor leo a, maximus nibh.</td>
          <td> Sed ut venenatis ligula, eget faucibus sapien</td>
        </tr>





      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!